# How to override / disable firefox menu shortkeys using Javascript for accesskey

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, access-keys

I have a web-application in which I use `accesskey` attribute to certain buttons. However I can't set <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> `accesskey` since it opens the **File** menu of the firefox. I have tried the following code

```
onkeydown = function(e){    
    if(e.altKey && e.keyCode == 'F'.charCodeAt(0)) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
    }
}
```

It doesn't seems like working in **firefox** but works fine in **chrome**. All other <kbd>alt</kbd> key combinations can be overridden except <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (file menu), <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>(Edit menu), <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>(View), <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>(History), <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>(Bookmark), <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>(Tools), <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>(Help) in **firefox**.

I am running it in Ubuntu. Is there a way to do it? It should be working in both Windows and Linux.

Comment: Do you have the option of using a less obtrusive key combination?  It might be of value to find a list of key combinations used by major browsers and avoid those.

Answer (score 0):

For <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> or <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
following piece of code will work.

```
onkeydown = function(e){    
   if(event.altKey && event.keyCode == 70) { 
      console.log("alt + f pressed")
      event.preventDefault(); 
   }
}
```

if by saying <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> - you mean you want to do <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>f/F</kbd> - following code will work in that case

```
onkeydown = function(e){    
   if(event.altKey && event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 70) { 
      console.log("alt + shift + f/F pressed")
      event.preventDefault(); 
   }
}
```

Rest of the combinations will work in similar manner
Refer to the key code chart [here](https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

Comment: It doesn't seems like working. I am testing it in Ubuntu 16.04 firefox. Still the menu pops up.

Comment: I'll try using ubuntu16.04 and firefox and let you know.